# Cell Highlighting for Worksheet Selection Change Event

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a selection change event in a worksheet where if there is a value within the cell, then remove the interior color of that cell to none. However, if there is no value, then keep the original interior color the same. And also, how would I restrict the selection change event to just a particular column only (minus empty cells of course). The vba code I was able to come up with so far is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Target.Value <> "" Then
     Target.Interior.Color = xlNone
  Else
     Target.Interior.Color = 13551615
  End If

End Sub
```

However, when I enter some data into the cell, the interior color did not change to none. Only when I click away and click back into that cell did the interior color change to none. What do I need to do to make the change instantaneous so that I don't have to click away and click back? Also, how would write in a restriction to only allow this selection change to occur within a particular column instead of the entire worksheet?

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Why not use conditional formatting?

Comment: Because I'm trying to automate the process via a macro. Conditional formatting would mean I have to manually select the data, click the conditional formatting button, and specify the conditions to format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter a value into a cell, your selection does not change. if you want to change the `Interior.Color` based on new values, you need to utilize the `Worksheet.Change` Event.

First off, regarding the restriction of the Range where the selection change should take effect:

Check if the selection (Target) and the range, in your case some cells in Column G  `Intersect`
Then, and this is optional, only make changes when one cell is selected and not more.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G2:G1000")) Is Nothing Then
        If Not Target.CountLarge > 1 Then
            If Target.Value <> "" Then
                Target.Interior.Color = xlNone
            Else
                Target.Interior.Color = 13551615
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

To recognize changes to the cell values, put the same code inside the `Worksheet.Change` Event Sub:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G2:G1000")) Is Nothing Then
        If Not Target.CountLarge > 1 Then
            If Target.Value <> "" Then
                Target.Interior.Color = xlNone
            Else
                Target.Interior.Color = 13551615
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

At this point you should probably outsource the code to a single sub and simply call it from the event subs.

Comment: Thank you! This worked like a charm! Many thanks!